# Acquaintances vs. Only Important updates on Facebook

Tags: facebook

Is there any difference between making someone an acquaintance or setting their updates to only important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Not only does putting someone in the "Acquaintances" list reduce the updates you get from them, you can more easily manage those people's permissions. For instance, when you add your work history you can set permission to "friends except acquaintances" (which is a default option on all permissions menus now).